# Scale an axis to scientific notation in Altair

Tags: python, altair

How can I scale my vertical axis to scientific notation in altair library. On the image below for example, there will be `5e10` instead of `50,000,000,000`.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_area().encode(
    x=alt.X("date:T"),
    y=alt.Y("time:Q"),
    color="type" 
)
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option you need to set is `format` using a [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format) code:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_area().encode(
    x=alt.X("date:T"),
    y=alt.Y("time:Q", axis=alt.Axis(tickCount=10, format=".1e"),
    color="type" 
)
```

The number before `e` in `".1e"` describes the number of digits to show :

[image]